# Как сделать историю для калькулятора?

Tags: javascript, html, css, калькулятор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать вот такую историю для калькулятора используя только JavaScript?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под историей?

Comment: @Grundy журнал, как в калькуляторе от Windows 10

Comment: @Grundy "Жил-был калькулятор ..."

Comment: @SeeSharp, что за журнал?

Comment: @Grundy история в котором будут сохронаться ответы

Comment: что за ответы имеются ввиду?

Comment: 5 + 5 = 10,
 10 - ответ, должен сохраниться в историй калькулятора

Comment: @Grundy https://i.stack.imgur.com/QobtV.png

Comment: @SabaKoguashvili, как ты хочешь определять, что полученный результат надо сохранить в историю?

Comment: я не знаю , поэтому задаю вопрос как сделать

Comment: все результаты должны сохроняться в историю

Comment: Что ты понимаешь под результатом?

Comment: напр: 5 + 5 = 10 , этот результат должен сохраниться в историю

Comment: а если вместо `=` ты опять нажмешь `+` ты должен сохранить промежуточный результат 10?

Comment: Четырнадцать комментариев ни о чем)) Ну для начала ваш пользователь вводит желаемое выражение и вы вычисляете результат. Следовательно у вас уже все данные где-то есть под рукой, если калькулятор написан: выражение + результат. Просто храните/выводите их в удобном виде и не теряйте сохраняя... да хотя бы в массив. А в продолжение определитесь, как вы будете их сохранять дальше т.к. вариантов у вас достаточно и время жизни у них разное: в течении сеанса, в куках, в localStorage, отправлять на сервер, <вписать свой вариант сумрачного гения>.

Answer (score 0):

Лично меня для хранения подобной информации крайне привлекали JSON строки и файлы. Мне удобно было их использовать как в вебе, так и на Андроиде. Пусть под каждое новое вычисление в массив JSON будет добавляться новый объект, в котором последовательно будут храниться использованные числа и операторы над ними, например вот так:

```js
{
  "number_1": 2,
  "operator_1": "+",
  "number_2": 2,
  "result": 4
}
```

Когда вам надо воспользоваться историей, программа просто последовательно выведет такие блоки, хранимые в файле. Стоит только написать рабочий интерпритатор, который правильно поймет это.
Краткую информацию по работе с JSON оставлю [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/json)

Answer (score 0):

Просто засунуть в массив объектов. Если в C++ то создать класс с нужными полями и дальше создать массив объектов этого класса.

```js
var exprs = [
  {
    "value1": 7,
    "symbol": "+",
    "value2": 9
  }
]

function evalute(exprobj)
{
  if (exprobj.symbol == "+")
  {
    return exprobj.value1 + exprobj.value2;
  }
}

function getExpr(exprobj)
{
    return exprobj.value1 + " " + exprobj.symbol + " " + exprobj.value2;
}


console.log(getExpr(exprs[0]));
console.log("=");
console.log(evalute(exprs[0]));
```